# ggplot: how to get this graph in depth?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Someone knows the code to generate a graph similar to this one?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Closest thing would probably be the ggridges package.

Comment: Hi OP.  What have you tried and can you share any part or aspect of your data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done using plotly. See an example below.  There are other packages for 3d plots.

```
  x <- c(1:30)
  y <- c(rep(0,30))
  y[4] <- 1
  y[19] <- 5
  z <- c(rep("THIQ",30))
  df1 <- data.frame(x,y,z)
  
  y <- c(rep(0,30))
  y[4] <- 0.8
  y[20] <- 4
  z <- c(rep("THIQ2",30))
  df2 <- data.frame(x,y,z)
  
  df <- rbind(df1,df2)
  
  plot_ly(x=df$x,  y=df$y, z=df$z,  color=df$z, 
          type="scatter3d",  mode="lines+markers", 
          marker = list(size = 1))
```

[image: output]